# Theme is working whole page in ipad jquery mobile

Tags: ipad, jquery-mobile

[image]

Hi

i am using `theme="a"`, `data-overlay-theme="a"` and `data-dismissible="false"`. But it is not working on whole page of iPad. How to apply on whole screen so that it look fine.

I also used this:

```
$(document).on('popupafteropen', '[data-role="popup"]', function(event, ui) {
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
}).on('popupafterclose', '[data-role="popup"]', function(event, ui) {
    $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
});
```

Here is my code.
jquery css

```
    .ui-popup-screen {
    background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==); /* Necessary to set some form of background to ensure element is clickable in IE6/7. While legacy IE won't understand the data-URI'd image, it ensures no additional requests occur in all other browsers with little overhead. */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    filter: Alpha(Opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1099;
}
.ui-popup-screen.in {
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: Alpha(Opacity=50);
}
.ui-popup-screen.out {
    opacity: 0;
    filter: Alpha(Opacity=0);
}
```

---

Structure Css**************************

```
.ui-popup-screen {
    background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==); /* Necessary to set some form of background to ensure element is clickable in IE6/7. While legacy IE won't understand the data-URI'd image, it ensures no additional requests occur in all other browsers with little overhead. */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    filter: Alpha(Opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1099;
}
.ui-popup-screen.in {
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: Alpha(Opacity=50);
}
.ui-popup-screen.out {
    opacity: 0;
    filter: Alpha(Opacity=0);
}
```

Comment: What in specific is not working? From what I can see on your image, popup overlay is not covering whole screen, is this it?

Comment: yes..You are right ..

Comment: Every functionality is working only pop up overy is not covering whole screen ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help, overlay **`DIV`** should now cover whole page, doesn't matter how much screen size is big or is content scrolled or not.

**CSS:**

```
.ui-popup-screen {
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    right: 0 !important;
    bottom: 0 !important;
    left:0 !important;
}
```

This **`CSS`** block has been tested in **`jsFiddle`** example so I can be 100% sure it will work. If not We will find another solution.

Comment: Are you doing something to customize popup CSS?

Comment: Tell me is this happening only on a emulator or also on a real iPad?

Comment: real ipad .I check on Ipad or tablet both

Comment: Just archive your app and mail it to me: dragan.gaic@gmail.com, I will be home in about 1 hour, there I have an iPad to test this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32149/discussion-between-user2484319-and-gajotres)